# Trying a quick cluster deployment with Docker:Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

Tags: database, docker, cluster-computing, dolphindb

I found that DolphinDB now supports a quick cluster deployment with docker containers and I followed the guide on github: https://github.com/dolphindb/Tutorials_CN/blob/master/docker_deployment.md to deploy a cluster with DolphinDB Docker package. But I encountered a problem. I looked at any other questions but can't find my own solution.

Here is the problem:

```
xllu@xllu-OptiPlex-7060:~/DolphinDB-Docker-Compose/Dockerbuild$ docker -v
Docker version 18.09.3, build 774a1f4
xllu@xllu-OptiPlex-7060:~/DolphinDB-Docker-Compose/Dockerbuild$ docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.24.0, build 0aa59064
xllu@xllu-OptiPlex-7060:~/DolphinDB-Docker-Compose/Dockerbuild$ docker build -t ddb:latest ./
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

I tried restarting docker:

```
xllu@xllu-OptiPlex-7060:~/DolphinDB-Docker-Compose/Dockerbuild$ sudo service docker restart
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Then I checked this :

```
xllu@xllu-OptiPlex-7060:~/DolphinDB-Docker-Compose/Dockerbuild$ systemctl status docker.service
● docker.service - LSB: Create lightweight, portable, self-sufficient containers.
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/docker; generated)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2019-05-31 15:16:01 CST; 16s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 29234 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/docker start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 2596 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

5月 31 15:16:01 xllu-OptiPlex-7060 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Create lightweight, portable, self-sufficient containers....
5月 31 15:16:01 xllu-OptiPlex-7060 docker[29234]:  * /usr/bin/dockerd not present or not executable
5月 31 15:16:01 xllu-OptiPlex-7060 systemd[1]: docker.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
5月 31 15:16:01 xllu-OptiPlex-7060 systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
5月 31 15:16:01 xllu-OptiPlex-7060 systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Create lightweight, portable, self-sufficient containers..
```

Comment: recheck your docker installation. See this from the logs. ```5月 31 15:16:01 xllu-OptiPlex-7060 docker[29234]:  * /usr/bin/dockerd not present or not executable```

Comment: does it work with `sudo`? its not a solution but if it works you only have to add yourself to the docker group

Comment: thank you, I reinstalled docker and  made it!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try removing `/var/lib/docker` with `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker` and try restarting the docker?

**You will lose the images stored**.